# How can I phrase this sentence so that it doesn't end in a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, syntactic-analysis, sentence-ends, prepositional-objects

Whenever possible, I like to avoid ending sentences with prepositions because some people can be very picky about it. However, I am struggling with this one sentence in particular:

"The hypothesis proposes that the selection against aggression led to other physiological and psychological changes that may not have been directly selected for."

The only alternative I can think of is "....for which were not directly selected", but in my opinion that sounds very awkward. Any suggestions for a better way to phrase that sentence? I believe that it would be acceptable to leave it as it is, but I would prefer not to if possible.

Comment: "...for which direct selection had not been made"?

Comment: That changes the meaning, though. As noted, "select for" is a phrasal verb.

Comment: The ending is fine. Some people are very picky about people who perform unnecessary gymnastics attempting to avoid finishing sentences with particles/prepositions. Including, if the rumour is correct, Churchill.

Comment: I gather this has to do with domestication and conscious selection, as opposed to natural selection. Thus " ... led to other *unintentional* physiological and psychological changes."  Also possible - "The hypothesis proposes that the selection against aggression may have brought with it other physiological and psychological changes that are associated through a [gene coexpression network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_co-expression_network)."

Comment: If you _really_ want to do this, move the adverb to the end: "may not have been selected for directly." But, as with most attempts to avoid this, it is a little awkward.

Comment: "The hypothesis proposes that other physiological and psychological changes may not have been directly selected for due to the [initial] selection against aggression."

Answer (score 1):

You can't do *for which,* because *select for* is [a phrasal verb which does not take an object](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/select).

Quite apart from being unnecessary in most cases, here it's absolutely essential to end with *for.*

Comment: 'Select for' is certainly transitive. 'Broad spectrum fluoroquinolones tend to select for drug-resistant pathogens.'

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary definition says "no object" but they give transitive examples, so I assume they consider the object of these to be indirect objects. Or something?

Comment: Yes. There is no direct object. One might "select for longevity," perhaps, but it doesn't indicate what is actually selected, only the result. Even Edwin's usage doesn't have a direct object.